# Linux hosts.deny settings are not applied

Tags: firewall, hosts

I want to make a bunch of websites unaccessible on my computer.

My `hosts.allow` file:

```
sendmail: all
# /etc/hosts.allow: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                   See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: LOCAL @some_netgroup
#             ALL: .foobar.edu EXCEPT terminalserver.foobar.edu
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
```

My `hosts.deny` file:

```
# /etc/hosts.deny: list of hosts that are allowed to access the system.
#                  See the manual pages hosts_access(5) and hosts_options(5).
#
# Example:    ALL: some.host.name, .some.domain
#             ALL EXCEPT in.fingerd: other.host.name, .other.domain
#
# If you're going to protect the portmapper use the name "rpcbind" for the
# daemon name. See rpcbind(8) and rpc.mountd(8) for further information.
#
# The PARANOID wildcard matches any host whose name does not match its
# address.
#
# You may wish to enable this to ensure any programs that don't
# validate looked up hostnames still leave understandable logs. In past
# versions of Debian this has been the default.
# ALL: PARANOID

ALL: .vk.com
ALL: .ria.ru
ALL: facebook.com
```

My `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1:82 testsecond
127.0.1.1   shc
127.0.2.2:81  someth.com
127.0.2.2:83 test

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe02::1 ip6-allnodes
fe02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I do follow all recommendations about settings hosts* files and 
I still CAN access them.  I must do something really stupid or wrong.

For me it looks like they are just ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hosts.deny` is for servers, *not* clients running on your computer therefore you can't block websites with it. I suggest reading the `hosts_access(5)` man page for your system ([Debian](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=hosts_access&sektion=5) version, [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hosts_access&sektion=5) version).

By the way, there's a proposal by Lennart Poettering [to get rid of tcpwrappers/tcpd](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2014-March/196913.html) in Fedora and [OpenSSH](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2014-April/032497.html) will do the same.

Comment: this is pretty not fair that it's not possible to use these files! so much time were wasted! Possible usage  of  /etc/hosts makes it even more confused